# One line fire and forget: void vs. async void + await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I have a `void` event handler that consists of exactly one line that's a call to an `await`able method.

```
void Handler( object sender, EventArgs args ) => AwaitableMethod();
```

Changing the return type to `Task` isn't an option, so it's fire-and-forget no matter the syntactic sugar.  Even so, Visual Studio puts a green squiggly under the un`await`ed call, suggesting I make the handler `async void` and `await` the call.

```
async void Handler( object sender, EventArgs args ) => await AwaitableMethod();
```

My understanding is that adding `async void` and `await` in this case would just be useless overhead.  Does Visual Studio know something that I don't know, or is it just being unnecessarily annoying?

Comment: The difference comes if the `Task` returned from `AwaitableMethod` ends up containing an exception. The first case will silently swallow it; the second will rethrow it. You're better off with the second option, and being aware that an exception occurred.

Comment: @canton7 Thanks for the tip!  I've got to refresh my memory about how exceptions work with `async`-`await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that adding async void and await in this case would just be useless overhead.

No.

If `Handler` returned a `Task`, then that would be true and [eliding `async`/`await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) would be fine; the code without `async`/`await` would just return the `Task` directly instead of "unwrapping" it with `await` and "wrapping" it back into a `Task` with `async`.

However, that's not the case here; `Handler` returns `void`, so the code without `async`/`await` will just ignore the returned `Task`, which is wrong the vast majority of the time (hence the compiler warning). Specifically, ignoring the `Task` will ignore any exceptions from that `Task`. It's also not possible for your code to know when an ignored `Task` has completed, but presumably that's acceptable since your handler is returning `void`.

There is a "registration" that `async void` methods do so that the framework is aware there is a task still in progress, so the framework knows when it's safe to shut down. The only .NET provided framework that actually cares about that is ASP.NET pre-Core; all other .NET-provided frameworks (including all UI frameworks) ignore that "registration".

Comment: Is there a way for one to catch an exception that has been thrown in an `async void` event handler? I realize you could have a try-catch _within_ the event handler, but I'm trying to see how simply adding `await` here as VS suggests would help from an exception-handling perspective.

Comment: @JLRishe you could subscribe to the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception) event.

Comment: @JLRishe: Without `await`, the exception is silently swallowed; that's almost never desired behavior. With `await`, any exception is passed directly to the `SynchronizationContext`. Most frameworks have a top-level exception handler where you can respond, such as `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException` or `Application.ThreadException`.

Comment: @StephenCleary I see. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks for the great answer. You said, "wrong the vast majority of the time". Could you elaborate on when it would not be wrong?

Comment: @HappyNomad: When the `Task` represents a top-level operation that has its own error handling (a top-level `try`/`catch` that catches all exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, it depends mostly on your error handling.

If `AwaitableMethod` asynchronously throws, it will throw on the UI thread on the second version.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest to avoid event handlers in this case and use something like this instead if possible.

```
 public class Eventful
    {
        private readonly List<Func<Task>> _handlers = new List<Func<Task>>();

        public void AddHandler(Func<Task> handler) => _handlers.Add(handler);

        private async Task RunHandlers()
        {
            foreach (var handler in _handlers)
            {
                await handler();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Consumer
    {
        public Consumer()
        {
            var eventful = new Eventful();
            eventful.AddHandler(async () =>
            {
                await DoAsyncTask();
            });
        }

        private static async Task DoAsyncTask()
        {
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add additional information as to how this answer solves the problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer